# Saving the TextBox Values in Registry

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, read-write

I need some guidance in reading/writing/saving the values in Registry.I am new to this concept of saving things in registry

I have a Winform where i have to read/write to a App.config file and change the username and password using a winform.In my winform i have 2 textboxes and when i enter values and hit submit it changes the values in app.config.I somehow did that and no issues.

Now I need to send what ever values I have entered in the Textboxes to registry and save them thr and I should also be able to read them.

How shoud I do that ?

Comment: Plenty of info about this on Google, [heres something to start with](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

Comment: Can't you make some simple google search ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a quick code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey exampleRegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("ExampleTest");
    exampleRegistryKey.SetValue("Name", textBox1.Text);
    exampleRegistryKey.Close();
}
```

Now if you run regedit and must see under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ExampleTest`

Answer (score 34):

`using Microsoft.Win32;`

To write:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProgram", "Username", "User1");
```

To read:

```
string username = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProgram",
                                    "Username", "NULL").ToString();
```

In read where I have put `NULL` - thats the value to return if the value you are looking for isn't there.

So if you did:

```
if(username == "NULL")
{
    // it doesn't exist, handle situation here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes Buddy.Thank you.... Do you have any Example to display here about this registry read/write/save ??

Comment: @user1410658 No probs. Updated question with actual data. If you had a key named `MyProgram` and you set the value `Username` with the first code and you get the value using the second. Once you make the change you don't need to save it.

Comment: @user1410658 No problem, if this answers your question you should accept it, just click the tick :D

Comment: Just to note: The route may translate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyProgram`.